# getenv("HOME") returns "/root" with "sudo"

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, root, sudo, getenv

I'm writing a program on my Raspberry Pi that requires the function "getenv("HOME")" to locate "/home/pi".

However, since I'm using the "wiringPi" library that requires "sudo" to run, "getenv("HOME")" now returns "/root" as the HOME directory instead of "/home/pi".

Is there a way to locate "/home/pi" with "getenv("HOME")" while using "sudo" the run the program?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you know the answer is `/home/pi`, why do you need `getenv("HOME")` to get the wrong value?  Presumably, calling `setenv("HOME", "/home/pi", 1)` is a bit too much like cheating, too?  Why are you sure that the value you need is `/home/pi`?  Why isn't `/root` correct when the program is run by `root` (or someone running `sudo`)?

Comment: There are many things you could do, including adding a command line option to your program to override use of `$HOME`, setting `$HOME` before running your program, looking first for a `$HOME_OVERRIDE` variable etc..

Comment: It's because "getenv("HOME")" is the code from another library I am trying to run, which I cannot change.
**setenv("HOME", "/home/pi", 1)** works for me, thanks @Jonathan Leffler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments and response into an answer.*</sup>

If you know the answer is `/home/pi`, why do you need `getenv("HOME")` to get the wrong value?

> It's because `getenv("HOME")` is the code from another library I am trying to run, which I cannot change.

Presumably, calling `setenv("HOME", "/home/pi", 1)` is a bit too much like cheating, too?

> `setenv("HOME", "/home/pi", 1)` works for me.

<s>Why are you sure that the value you need is `/home/pi`? Why isn't `/root` correct when the program is run by root (or someone running sudo)?</s>

This becomes mostly immaterial given that there's another unchangeable library involved.

In that case, setting the correct value for the environment variable before invoking the other library is a mostly reasonable mechanism.